# logging module in virtualenv

Tags: python, logging, virtualenv

Ubuntu 12.10

While trying to get flask+logging to work in a virtualenv, I discovered that it seems the logging module is NOT getting imported from the virtualenv (last line in snippet below).

(I think this is having the side effect of not printing to the log file when my flask app is run inside a virtualenv, but I'll ask that separately if this question doesn't help)

Why is this?? Is the logging module somehow special?

```
# system python
# imports come from /usr/lib/python2.7 as expected

me@home:~/Desktop$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re; print re
<module 're' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>                          # OK
>>> import logging; print logging
<module 'logging' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>       # OK
>>> exit()

# make virtual env

me@home:~/Desktop$ virtualenv --version
14.0.0
me@home:~/Desktop$ virtualenv testenv
New python executable in /home/me/Desktop/testenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

# Try again inside venv

me@home:~/Desktop$ source testenv/bin/activate
(testenv) me@home:~/Desktop$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re; print re
<module 're' from '/home/me/Desktop/testenv/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>     # OK!
>>> import logging; print logging
<module 'logging' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>      # WHY?
```

Comment: FWIW, on MacOS I don't have any locally copied modules that are part of the "standard" python 3.5 group. I wonder if the `--always-copy` option would help here?

Comment: I tried your suggestion by making a virtualenv with: `$ virtualenv --always-copy testenv` but the result was the same.

Comment: Saw your comment - `--always-copy` just makes copies of *certain* files, instead of symlinking them. It doesn't copy them all. Why would you want logging to be copied to the virtualenv? What's special about logging that you want that?

Comment: After some debugging, it turned out my original problem which led to this SO question, had a different root cause. Brief summary: In a flask app "A" inside virtualenv, the logging was not going to the file I specified. In a complete separate flask app "B" running on the system python, the logging was working as expected. This led me to believe the cause was the logging module not getting copied into the virtual env. It turned out the problem was that I was doing `logging.info("...")` *before* calling `logging.basicConfig(filename=...)` in app "A", but not in app "B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Most* modules in the Python standard library are not copied to the virtualenv - only the select few which are needed for the virtualenv to function correctly. So what you are seeing is normal.

Comment: Even with the `--always-copy` option? If so, how can I get the `logging` module (in my specific case) to be copied to and loaded from the virtualenv?